# Upload website + database to dropbox with PHP

Tags: php, upload, dropbox

Does anyone know, if it's possible to backup my website and database to a dropbox account with php or something?
And if it's possible, how can I do it the best way? :-)

Best Regards
Simon

Comment: do you mean to say you want to host your PHP file and Database in Dropbox or you want to use Dropbox API to transfer files to Dropbox using PHP?

Comment: I want to upload the files and database to dropbox via. the api, so I have a backup in the cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, have a look at the [dropbox-php](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API).

Example Code from the documentation:

```
/* Please supply your own consumer key and consumer secret */
$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';

include 'Dropbox/autoload.php';

session_start();
$oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PHP($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

// If the PHP OAuth extension is not available, you can try
// PEAR's HTTP_OAUTH instead.
// $oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PEAR($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$dropbox = new Dropbox_API($oauth);

$dropbox->putFile('newPath.txt','/local/path/tofile');
```

Comment: Cool, didn't knew that, thanks! But do you know a more workable example which can upload a folder and a database?

Comment: Yes, depends on the database. I'd suggest to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), which is a filebased sql-enabled database and thus may be uploaded into dropbox. As for all other databases, you'll run into problems or have to take really weird paths. However, as @str pointed out, you won't be able to run any code on your dropbox, but will have to copy it to a real webspace with a php interpreter. As for the example with folders: Please check the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that is possible.
You need the solution from Lars and a webserver for your dropbox,
check https://github.com/louissobel/Drapache