# Dropbox API without user action, standalone app

Tags: php, api, dropbox

I'm trying to develop a PHP script to synchronize files with a Dropbox folder that I own.

I'm trying to connect using the Core API and OAuth 2, and it seems that a user needs to get an authorization code from an approval page, but my script needs to be stand alone without any user interaction.

My question is : is it possible ?
I didn't find anything to the Dropbox API documentation to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for any link, help or alternatives.

Comment: If you just want to backup / sync your own files this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234934/upload-website-database-to-dropbox-with-php

Comment: You can log-in once, store access token and it will work until you revoke this token via web panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dev-null-dweller said in a comment, you certainly need to authorize the app once, but you can just store the token and keep reusing it.

You might want to use my app http://dbxoauth2.site44.com/ to get an OAuth token for yourself and then just hardcode it in your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I authorized the app once, and it seems to work like a charm !